# D3 rect + color does not display

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am toying around with D3 to create a heat map. I am creating NxN squares which color I would like to change adjust. However, only the first square displays in blue, the remaining are there according to the html inspector and have the color set, but they dont show up on the page.

```
    size = 30;
    length = myJSON.length;
    numRows = length /2;
    numCols = length / 2;

    var svg = d3.select("div#heatchart").append("svg").attr("width",size).attr("height",size);

    svg.selectAll("rect").data(myJSON).enter().append("rect").attr("x",function(d,i){
        var x = Math.floor(i%numRows) * (size+1);
        return x;
    }).attr("y",function(d,i){
        var y = Math.floor(i/numCols) * (size+1);
        return y;
    }).attr("width",function(d,i){
        return size;
    }).attr("height",function(d,i){
        return size;
    }).attr("fill", function(d,i) {
        return "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    });
```

Comment: data, nothing particular. As you see I right now use the index i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an svg group element (`<g>` - *this is not true see edit*).

Modify so it looks like this

```
var svg = d3.select("div#heatchart")
            .append("svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("width", size)
            .attr("height", size);
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/4tz5wk91/

**edit**
This example works but not for the reason stated. The attr functions no longer affect the svg element and as a result it gets a default size which is big enough to display all elements. The width and height attributes applied to the group actually have no effect in this case. See @jshanley's more complete and correct solution.

Comment: You don't need a group to append multiple svg elements. As the OP noted in the question, the elements appear in the element inspector. The reason they don't show up is that they are drawn outside the borders of the svg element. See my answer.

Comment: @jshanley. I see you are correct. I checked my solution and inserted an explanation of why it works. El Dude you should accept jshanleys answer instead of mine. If that's not possible I can delete my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're only seeing one square is that you've set the dimensions of your `<svg>` element to be equal to the variable `size` which is only 30. The other squares are being drawn, but they are outside the bounds of the svg document and so are invisible.

Once you fix that, you are still going to run into issues with the layout because you are setting the number of rows and columns based on dividing `length` in half. What you really want to do to make an NxN square is to base the number of rows and columns on the square root of `length`. You can use `Math.ceil` to round up in case your data length is not a perfect square. Try it like this:

```
var size = 30;
var n = myJSON.length;
var numRows = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n)),
    numCols = numRows;
```

Then you can set the size of your svg based on how many rows and columns you need to display:

```
var svg = d3.select('div#heatchart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', size * numCols)
  .attr('height', size * numRows);
```

Finally, arrange them in a square, setting the fill to blue:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(myJSON)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d,i) { return (i % numCols) * size; })
    .attr('y', function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i / numRows) * size; })
    .attr('width', size)
    .attr('height', size)
    .attr('fill', 'blue');
```

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/vulemo/1/edit?js,output) is an example.